# Q: Algebraic Loop Error (Simulink)

Tags: matlab, loops, simulink, algebraic-data-types

I am building a Maximum Power Point Tracker (MPPT) configuration for solar array on simulink and i am facing an algebraic loop error. I've tried using a unit delay to rectify this problem but it came to no avail as I might have done it wrongly. Below is the error message:

[image: Error Message on Simulink]

Also, my MPPT model is as shown below:

[image: MPPT]

Your help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried an Initial Condition block? [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/ic.html)

Comment: Did you try the suggested possibilities to solve the problem?